# How to reverse proxy via VPN tunnel?

Tags: vpn, reverse-proxy

I would like to be able to use my Nextcloud instance with a local server, however I can't control port forwarding on my network.

What I would want to try do is as follows:

1. Use an external server (OCI\AWS\etc.).
2. Install a VPN service on the server
3. Install an NGINX server on the server.
4. Connect to the VPN from my nextcloud server inside my network.
5. Configure the NGINX on the server as a reverse proxy for my server.

Is it possible?

Can the NGINX server on the remote server have route to my local server, when the local server is the machine that does the tunneling?

Comment: Yrs, this ispossible- but does not call for a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the NGINX server on the remote server have route to my local server

Yes, that's kind of the whole job of the VPN.

> when the local server is the machine that does the tunneling?

It isn't; both machines are. IP tunnels work on individual packets, so they're always bidirectional regardless of which side initiated the tunnel.

Comment: So... you're saying I can use my VPN for bidirectional connection... interesting...  I guess I will need to connect to the VPN via my phone, in order to have access to the server... OK. The followup question will be: Will conneting my home server to the VPN allow connecting to the Nextcloud instace, running via snaps?